# SQL: GROUP BY and get first two biggest COUNTs for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

Table: signin

---

| username | class |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 |
| aaa | 1 |
| bbb | 1 |
| bbb | 1 |
| ccc | 1 |
| ddd | 2 |
| ddd | 2 |
| eee | 2 |

There are two classes. How do I get first **TWO** `username` who has the most total count for each class(class-1 & class-2) like below ↓.

| username | class | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2 |
| bbb | 1 | 2 |
| ddd | 2 | 2 |
| eee | 2 | 1 |

**EDIT:** Is there any way not using `over partition by`?

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? MySQL in generally not referred to as Oracle MySQL despite the fact it is developed and supported by this vendor. Oracle tag says it is about [Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html), so it is confusing here (and Oracle provides much more functionality compared to MySQL, so answers will be very different).

Comment: I removed oracle tag and added mysql-5.7 for I didn't realize this could lead to answers that using oracle feature which is not compatible with older version of mysql.

Comment: This is because other DBMSes had this feature for years

Comment: With TOP n questions you should always think about ties. Your title says "the two biggest COUNTs", but the two biggest counts for type 1 are 2 and 1 and you don't show user c with a count of 1. So what exactly is the rule? Let's say these are the users and counts for one class: a/5, b/5, c/5, d/3, e/3, f/1, g/1. Which would you show? Two top rows, i.e. two of the users a, b, and c arbitrarily picked? All three in order to treat them fairly? None, because two rows is the maximum and you don't want an indeterminate result?

Comment: @Kim if any of the query answered your question please accept that.

Answer (score 2):

In older version of MySQL you need to generate the ranking manually without any ranking function. Below code will work.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table signin(username varchar(50),class int);

 insert into signin values('aaa',   1);
 insert into signin values('aaa',   1);
 insert into signin values('bbb',   1);
 insert into signin values('bbb',   1);
 insert into signin values('ccc',   1);
 insert into signin values('ddd',   2);
 insert into signin values('ddd',   2);
 insert into signin values('eee',   2);
```

Query:

```
 select username,class,total 
 from
     (
       select username,class,count(*) total ,
       @rn := IF(@prev = class, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
       @prev := class
       from signin
       JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
       group by class,username
       order by class,username,count(*) desc
     )t
 where rn<=2
```

Output:

| username | class | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2 |
| bbb | 1 | 2 |
| ddd | 2 | 2 |
| eee | 2 | 1 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=926e55bc52e981ad0619cce34a1c7b6b)*

Answer (score 1):

Rank them by *count* in descending order and display only the first two. Sample data in lines #1 - 10; query begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with signin (username, class) as
  2    (select 'aaa', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'aaa', 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'bbb', 1 from dual union all
  5     select 'bbb', 1 from dual union all
  6     select 'ccc', 1 from dual union all
  7     select 'ddd', 2 from dual union all
  8     select 'ddd', 2 from dual union all
  9     select 'eee', 2 from dual
 10    )
 11  select username, class, total
 12  from (select username, class, count(*) total,
 13          rank() over (partition by class order by count(*) desc) rnk
 14        from signin
 15        group by username, class
 16       )
 17  where rnk <= 2
 18  order by class, username;

USE      CLASS      TOTAL
--- ---------- ----------
aaa          1          2
bbb          1          2
ddd          2          2
eee          2          1

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there any other way not using over partition by statement? MySQL does not support this.

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't speak MySQL. Why did you tag the question with **Oracle** tag, then?

Comment: Mysql does support it, unless you are using a very old version

Answer (score 1):

With `rank()` ranking window function and common table expression you can easily achieve that.

To get the usernames with most count in a class I have used `rank()over (partition by class order by count(*) desc)` along with `group by class,username`

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table signin(username varchar(50),class int);
 insert into signin values('aaa',   1);
 insert into signin values('aaa',   1);
 insert into signin values('bbb',   1);
 insert into signin values('bbb',   1);
 insert into signin values('ccc',   1);
 insert into signin values('ddd',   2);
 insert into signin values('ddd',   2);
 insert into signin values('eee',   2);
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
     select username,class,count(*) total, 
     rank()over (partition by class order by count(*) desc) rn
     from signin
     group by class,username
 )
 select username,class,total from cte where rn<=2
```

Output:

| username | class | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2 |
| bbb | 1 | 2 |
| ddd | 2 | 2 |
| eee | 2 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b0dadf0a0c8e1befe4b45c3713e043f)*

Comment: Is there any other way not using `over partition by` statement? MySQL does not support this.

Comment: You are using mysql or oracle? MySQL 8 supports this.

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Currently I'm using MySQL 5.7 @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is not a good choice. If there was e.g. ` insert into signin values('ccc',   1);`, your query would return only two usernames, although they would then be equal as aaa, bbb and ccc would each have 2 rows.

Comment: @Littlefoot got your point. Changed my answer with rank() instead. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, Kazi :)

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL, you would use variables.  But you have to be careful with the syntax.

The basic idea is aggregation and then enumeration:

```
select uc.*
from (select uc.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = class, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := class, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from (select username, class, count(*) as cnt
            from signin
            group by username, class
            order by class, cnt desc
           ) uc cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
     ) uc
where seqnum <= 2;
```

There are three very important things to remember when using variables in a `select`:

1. They are deprecated.  In more recent versions, you should be using window functions for this type of operation.
2. MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  So, you should handle all variables in a single expression, which is why the `@rn :=`  is rather complicated.
3. MySQL does not guarantee that the `ORDER BY` is evaluated before the variable assignments.  That is why the `ORDER BY` is in the subquery.